On which episode of NCIS was Gibbs not 'the boss'?
I remember there was an episode of NCIS where Gibbs wasn't 'the boss' of the team, but I can't remember which one it was.
I've got a vague feeling that Tony was put in charge and they swapped chairs, Tony sat in Gibbs's seat and Gibbs sat in Tony's seat.

Would the down-voter care to explain why this is a bad question?

In the first episode, they call Ducky the boss but that is to confuse the FBI.

In season 3 / episodes 23 and 24 "Hiatus" Tony becomes the temporary team leader because Gibbs is wounded.
In season 6 / episode 16 "Bounce" Tony becomes team leader because of rule #38 "Your case, your lead". This is probably the episode you are referring to.

It was indeed "Bounce" that I was thinking of. I don't have access to the episodes to check, but I found some quotes from the episode that seem to fit what I remember.
